# Disable Fetch association mapping with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I have trouble with JPA/Hibernate, no matter what I set **fetch = FetchType.Lazy** or **fetch = FetchType.Eager**.

My custom method not working (when debug, I see answers collection is PersistentBag and whenever I call getter, the answer is actually created and some condition with **WITH** in my custom was not applied). 
That's what I dont want, I want it will be set at my custom method.

Question is :

1, Am I doing right, disable fetch type and set association at hql query ?

2, If I am doing right, why it's not working, association only when call getter  ?

3, If I am wrong, Please tell me how to implement this.

Thanks for reading .

My `Parent` class :

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Question.findAll", query="SELECT q FROM Question q")
public class Question implements Serializable {

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Answer
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Answer> answers;

  ...
}
```

And `Child` class :

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Answer.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Answer a")
public class Answer implements Serializable {

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Question
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="question_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Question question;

  ...

}
```

In My custom method , I'm using HQL as :

```
    public List<Question> search() {

        String sql = "SELECT distinct(question)"
                + " FROM Question as question "
                + " LEFT JOIN question.answers as answer with answer.isDeleted = true";

        List<Question> result = query.getResultList();

        return result;
    }
```

PS. I found I have very similar issue with this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/1372725 
but I dont know how to follow his instruction.

Answer (score 1):

JPA doesn't provide any specification on mapping annotations to select fetch strategy. In general, related entities can be fetched in any one of the ways given below

- SELECT => one query for root entities + one query for related mapped entity/collection of each root entity = (n+1) queries
- SUBSELECT => one query for root entities + second query for related mapped entity/collection of all root entities retrieved in first query = 2 queries
- JOIN => one query to fetch both root entities and all of their mapped entity/collection = 1 query

Set your @OneToMany with fetch=FetchType.LAZY and add @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
Then your query will working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This query

```
SELECT distinct(question)
  FROM Question as question
  LEFT JOIN question.answers as answer with answer.isDeleted = true
```

means the same as

```
SELECT distinct(question)
  FROM Question
```

This query

```
SELECT distinct(question)
  FROM Question as question
  INNER JOIN question.answers as answer with answer.isDeleted = true
```

means get `questions` that have at least one answer with `isDeleted = true`.

To fetch a lazy association `join fetch` can be used

```
 SELECT distinct(question)
      FROM Question as question
      LEFT JOIN FETCH question.answers
```

But, I think, it is impossible to fetch an association with a condition.
There is an example using `EclipseLink`:

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com.by/2012/04/objects-vs-data-and-filtering-join.html#Filtering

You can try something similar with Hibernate. I think, it will not work.

Other option is use `@Where`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="question",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = 0")
private List<Answer> answers;
```

But, probably, it doesn't suitable to you, because of it is impossible to disable `@Where` clause. You will never have all answers with fetching.

So better to load answers with condition with a separate query.